# Find the median between averages of row blocks

Tags: excel

If I have a table like this:

[image: this]

How would I implement a `=MEDIAN` formula so that it populates the median for B2:B4, and then B5:B7 and so forth for each cities data?

I know it would be something like wrapping around an `=IF(B2<>B3` kind of statement with the `=MEDIAN`, but I'm getting stuck trying to combine the two.

For City 1, (rows 2:4) I would just want the median of column F's data in G2. City 2, I would want the same in G5. ANd so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array Formula if G2 then copy down.

```
=IF(A1<>A2,MEDIAN(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$F$2:$F$7)),"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.